# Reference not works

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I need pass the reference of `i` to `.then` callback

```
var promises = loadScript(assets["js"][0]);
  for (var i = 1; i < assets["js"].length; i++){
    promises = promises.then(function() { loadScript(assets["js"][i]) });
  }
```

I tried this:

```
var promises = loadScript(assets["js"][0]);
  for (var i = 1; i < assets["js"].length; i++){
    promises = promises.then((function(i){loadScript(assets["js"][i])})(i));
  }
```

Here the function is executed before the `.then` method call

Return from the then

```
var promises = loadScript(assets["js"][0]);
  for (var i = 1; i < assets["js"].length; i++){
    promises = promises.then( function() { return loadScript(assets["js"][i]) });
  }
```

I get the error:

```
i = undefined
```

Comment: You're not `return`ing from the `then`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum — They're not trying to do anything with the return value … so what does that matter?

Comment: I dont understand.. This is a promise, why a i need do something with the return? I just use .then and finally i can use $q.all(), not? I need the specific idx of loop to start a promise based on array value